# handle click event on button with jQuery in dhtmlx grid after smart rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I'm generating a DHTMLX grid that has to show a big dataset (+ 2K rows). 
In the last column of the grid there are three buttons defined with html.

I'm handling the "click" event on this buttons with jQuery :

```
$("button.edit").on("click", function() {
some stuff ...
});
```

First try was to put this jQuery code the normal way :

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...}
```

This was not working so I put the jQuery in the event "onXLE" of the grid construction

```
mygrid.attachEvent("onXLE", function() {
    $("button.edit").on("click", function() {
    some stuff ...
    });
})
```

This is working fine but because it's a big dataset and due to network performance I decided to use the smartrendering method of the grid.

```
mygrid.enableSmartRendering(true);
```

The problem I'm facing now is that the buttons on the first records work like a charm but when you scroll down and more records are rendered the buttons with these records don't work anymore.

Has anyone a solution on this ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

My clue is that you must attach function of yours on the event 'onDataReady'.

usage according to Dhtmlx Docs:
"fires when the data is loaded to the grid but hasn't been rendered yet"

```
mygrid.attachEvent("onDataReady",function(){
    // your code here
});
```

I think this is pretty much what you need.